# Environment variables in meteor command line for windows

Tags: meteor

trying to set an environment variable in meteor command line on windows fails.
e.g `JASMINE_BROWSER=PhantomJS meteor [options]` returns

```
'JASMINE_BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

please how can one set environment variables in meteor command line?

Comment: I don't remember how to do this, but it's not a problem specific to meteor. Google how to set environment variables on Windows and you'll get an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use SET e.g. 
SET JASMINE_BROWSER=PhantomJS meteor [options]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **cross-env**:

`npm i -g cross-env`

`cross-env JASMINE_BROWSER=PhantomJS meteor`